# How to use fontawesome 5 with context?

Tags: context, fontawesome

I have installed `mactex-no-gui` and it contains `context` and  `fontawesome5`.

```
> sudo tlmgr install fontawesome5                        
Password:
tlmgr: package repository http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package already present: fontawesome5
```

Let’s say I have the following file named `test.tex`.

```
\usesymbols[fontawesome]
\setupsymbolset[fontawesome]

\symbol[globe]
\symbol[beer]
\symbol[discord]
```

Then, the following command creates a PDF file with `fontawesome 4` but not with `fontawesome 5`.

```
context test.tex --pdf-engine=xelatex
```

Next, I tried the following file,

```
\usesymbols[fontawesome5]
\setupsymbolset[fontawesome5]

\symbol[globe]
\symbol[beer]
\symbol[discord]
```

but it returned error like this.

```
fonts           > symbols > library 'fontawesome5' is unknown
```

I can’t find any solution so far. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConTeXt supports version 5 of Font Awesome but the provided symbolset works only with `MkIV`.

```
\usesymbols [fontawesome]

\starttext

\symbol [fontawesome-solid] [globe]

\stoptext
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks.